# Laravel blade, recursive view with php translated to blade

Tags: laravel

I have this recursive view with php, which is plain wrong so I have to translate this to blade, for recursive call for a view.

**My php recursive code in (comments.blade.php):**

```
<?php
tree($Comments, 0, 0);
$var = -1;
function tree($Comments, $parent_id = 0, $level=0, $c=0) {
  global $var;
  foreach($Comments as $Comment) {
      if($Comment['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
        If ($level > $var)  $var++; else {  
                for ($i = $var-$level+1; $i>0; $i--) { if ($c < 0) echo '</div> </div>'; else $c--;  };   
                $var=$level; 
                   }; 
        echo '<div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                  <a href="#">
                  <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
                  </a>
                </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>';
        tree($Comments, $Comment['id'], $level+1,$c);
        }
  };
};
?>
```

**And that's what I am looking for(in comments.blade.php:**

```
<div>
    @include('recursive', ['comments' => $comments, 'parent_id' => 0, 'level' => 0, 'c' => 0])
</div>
```

**The thing is I don't know how to translate all that variables in first snippet of code into blade, so to create Recursive.blade.php:**

**Edit 1:**

Guys please help me, I worked 2 days on this damn algorithm and I am stuck once again in a problem even bigger then it was 2 days ago :(

For some people that doesn't understand why I am sticking with that code is because that code above is the algorithm for making the threaded comments like that on reddit, in the algorithm there is 2x echo, and a media class echo.
If i put 2x  after the media class on 2 comments in a row, the next one comment will create with first one, comments with same parent_id, this means they are childs that belong to the same comment(parent before them), If the 2x div are not put then this means the next one comment after first is the child of the first and so on. This is my algorithm, i am doing this to translate to blade because I have some cheeky votes buttons which uses routes that i will integrate into recursive design, that's why i want to be translate to blade, but i don't know how. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you call the recursively for generating the view, you can make an file name comment.blade.php and run a loop inside main blade file which will include the comment.blade.php and pass the comment object or array and then the comment.blade.php file will user the properties of that $comment object or array.

For example:

```
  $Comments = [
    [
      'body' => 'First comment',
      'name' => 'First Commentator'
    ],
    [
      'body' => 'Second comment',
      'name' => 'Second Commentator'
    ],
    [
      'body' => 'Third comment',
      'name' => 'Third Commentator'
    ],
    [
      'body' => 'Fourth comment',
      'name' => 'Fourth Commentator'
    ],
    [
      'body' => 'Fifth comment',
      'name' => 'Fifth Commentator'
    ],
    [
      'body' => 'Sixth comment',
      'name' => 'Sixth Commentator'
    ],
  ];
```

and in your main blade file that can be index.blade.php or any other

```
  @foreach($Comments as $Comment)
    @include('comment',['comment'=>$comment])
  @endforeach
```

comment.blade.php file would have

```
<div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
      <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: because that code above is the algorithm for making the threaded comments like that on reddit, if I do as you do, then I get a static view of comments with (imaginary parent_id=0). I really need somehow to convert that stuff I provided in php in blade, any help :(?

Comment: @DomainFlag Does the threaded comment has the same html design and just comes inside the main comment div?

Comment: first question yes, you see that div class=media code and the 2</div> at the end? If i put 2x </div>, the next one comment will  create with first one, comments with same parent_id, this means they are childs that belong to the same comment(parent), If the 2x div are not put then this means the next one comment after first is the child of the first and so on. This is my algorithm, i am doing this to translate to blade because I have some cheeky votes buttons which uses routes that i will integrate into recursive design, that's why i want to be translate to blade, but i don't know how :(

Comment: Or how could I integrate   <a href="{{route('vote', ['id' => $Comment->id, 'vote' => 'plus'  ])}}"> <img class="media-object" style="height:40px; width:40px;" src="{{ URL::asset("images/upVote.svg") }}" ></a> this into php code so the route will work, below that medialeft class design, but i don't like this :(?

Comment: I have an ideea, put that shit algorithm in the controller so instead of viewing that class media, create an array/object ordered with comments values and special values(how many divs should place), is it good? it is returned to view to show them

Comment: Yes that's what I was saying.

Answer (score 1):

There is a automatic tool for get this job done. check out [PHP2Blade](https://github.com/smarteist/PHP2Blade)

you can convert multiple files to blade syntax by runnig this command.

```
php php2blade <files directory> <optional output directory>
```